# Возможно ли при закрытии приложения или его запуске изменить SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

В SharedPreferences хранится число 1. В приложении я меняю его на 5:

```
editor.remove("count");
editor.putInt("count", 5);
```

В течении работы приложения оно таким и остается (даже при сворачивании). Если полностью закрыть приложение и вновь его открыть то число остается 5. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при новом запуске приложения оно опять было 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharedPreferences используются именно для постоянного хранения данных. Если значение вам нужно только во время работы приложения, то сохраняйте его в памяти. Например в классе наследнике `Application`:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static App INSTANCE;

    private int count = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        INSTANCE = this;
    }

    public void setCount(int newCount) {
        count = newCount;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Получать значение `App.INSTANCE.getCount()`. Устанавливать `App.INSTANCE.setCount(5)`.

При закрытии приложения значение будет сбрасываться а при открытии устанавливаться в 1.

И не забудьте прописать класс `App` в манифесте:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.App"
    ...
```

Comment: eugeneek, а если таких значений много, возможно ли такое проделать с массивом?

Comment: Да. Можно с любым типом данных.

Comment: eugeneek а возможно ли взять и установить значение в Adapter?

Comment: @Anna13 Переделал код, для доступа из любого класса. Либо, вы можете получить значение в активити и передать его в адаптер. Например, через конструктор.

Comment: eugeneek, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Посадите в `onDestroy()` вызов типа:

```
editor.putInt("count", 1);
editor.commit();
```

а в `onCreate()` - читайте его и все

Comment: Вызов `onDestroy()` [не гарантируется](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()): *Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data!*

Comment: Я вообще то не имел ввиду `Application` - имелся ввиду `Activity`

Comment: Да, я тоже про `Activity`.